# Rescaling UI Elements before Screen (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement a PrintPreview for my WPF app. And I'm having an issue with resizing and redrawing the elements. I have a Plot (OxyPlot) that I want to keep at a fixed size (700x400) for the Print Page no matter the size of the window. So I have NewPrint() finding the element, resizing it and then rendering the bitmap for the print page.

It works, but only after second time, and I think it's because the UI Element doesn't update until the window is rendered. The first time (image on left), if I do the print preview, it doesn't resize. But the second time (image on right) it resizes correctly.

I've tried doing UpdateLayout() but that makes the bitmap blank for some reason. Then I considered OnRender() but am concerned that it will consume resources inefficiently. How do I update the layout before rendering the bitmap?

This approach was my attempt but can someone give me some guidelines on how to resize an element to a fixed size and then rendering an image?

[image]

```
private void NewPrint(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPreview printPreview = new PrintPreview();            
        var FoundPlotView = this.FindFirstChild<PlotView>();
        if (FoundPlotView != null)
        {
            var plotsize = new Size(700, 400);
            FoundPlotView.Measure(plotsize);
            FoundPlotView.Arrange(new Rect(plotsize));
            //FoundPlotView.UpdateLayout();
            //FoundPlotView.InvalidateArrange();
            //FoundPlotView.InvalidateMeasure();
            //(FoundPlotView.Parent as FrameworkElement).UpdateLayout();

            FoundPlotView.InvalidatePlot(true);
        }

        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(700, 400, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(FoundPlotView);
        printPreview.ppmodel.Image1 = bmp;

        printPreview.Show();
        //if (FoundPlotView != null)
        //{
        //    FoundPlotView.Height = Double.NaN;
        //    FoundPlotView.Width = Double.NaN;
        //}
        //if (FoundPlotView2 != null)
        //{
        //    FoundPlotView2.Height = Double.NaN;
        //    FoundPlotView2.Width = Double.NaN;
        //}

    }
```

Comment: Have you also tried `InvalidateVisual()` after Measure and Arrange? As a note, you should adhere to naming conventions and name the variable `foundPlotView`. Also, if you use `var`, use it whenever possible, i.e. `var printPreview` and `var bmp`.

Comment: Not sure if OxPlot is perhaps rendering asynchronously, but you could also try to declare the event handler `async` and call `await Task.Delay()` with a reasonable delay time before `bmp.Render`.

Comment: As a note, it seems odd to rearrange the existing PlotView element from the visual tree. Consider creating a new one that shows the same data.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, I also tried InvalidateVisual, but same result. And thanks for the tips! And yes, its weird...I rearrange the PlotView element but I have to undo that change (the code to Double.NaN at the end) to reset the size of the element to Auto.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up doing it.
I ended up subscribing the to LayoutUpdated event to run the bitmap render. and then I unsubscribe.

```
private void NewPrint(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var FoundPlotView = this.FindFirstChild<PlotView>();
        if (FoundPlotView != null)
        {
            var plotsize = new Size(700, 400);
            FoundPlotView.Measure(plotsize);
            FoundPlotView.Arrange(new Rect(plotsize));
        }
        this.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(Window_Loaded);
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var printPreview = new PrintPreview();
        var FoundPlotView = this.FindFirstChild<PlotView>();
        if (FoundPlotView != null)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(700, 400, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            bmp.Render(FoundPlotView);
            printPreview.ppmodel.Image1 = bmp;
        }

        printPreview.Show();
        this.LayoutUpdated -= new EventHandler(Window_Loaded);
        if (FoundPlotView != null)
        {
            FoundPlotView.Height = Double.NaN;
            FoundPlotView.Width = Double.NaN;
            (FoundPlotView.Parent as FrameworkElement).InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }
```